# Is gl_FragData[0] always a color buffer?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

From the few examples I have seen around the net, gl_FragData[0] is assumed to be a color buffer. I tried to find the meaning of each index into gl_FragData and came across this passage from OpenGL Shading language book (orange book)

> gl_FragData is an array that can be assigned values that are written
>   into one or more offscreen buffers. The size of this array is
>   implementation dependent and can be queried with glGet with the
>   symbolic constant GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS. The offscreen buffers that are
>   modified as a result of writing values into gl_FragData within a
>   fragment shader are specified with glDrawBuffers. The value written
>   into gl_FragData[0] updates the first buffer in the list specified in
>   the call to glDrawBuffers, the value written into gl_FragData[1]
>   updates the second buffer in the list, and so on.

It's not specified that 0th value of gl_FragData is always color buffer. If there is such specification, where can I find it? If not, what is a normal practice when writing to gl_FragData?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't have to be a color buffer per-se. But if it's not a color buffer, then it's *nothing*.

The `gl_FragData` output array refers to the values set by [`glDrawBuffers`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawBuffers). And when using an FBO, the values you pass to this function can only be `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTn` or `GL_NONE`. Which, as the names state, are color buffers.

So it's either a color buffer or it's `GL_NONE`.

For GL ES implementations that don't offer `glDrawBuffers` (ie, that don't implement [NV_draw_buffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/NV_draw_buffers.txt)), it is defined as though index zero was set to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`.

It is silly of ES 2.0 to allow for the possibility of multiple attachments without actually providing a way to *render* to more than one of them...

Comment: I suppose glDrawBuffers is not available in OpenGL ES. In that case does the FBO implicitly calls it at some point?

Comment: `glDrawBuffers` (do not confuse with `glDrawBuffer`, very intelligent choice of names...) is part of ARB_draw_buffers, which is OpenGL 2.0 core. Since OpenGL ES 2.0 is defined relative to OpenGL 2.0, it should include that function.

Comment: @Damon: Technically, [`glDrawBuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawBuffer) is defined in terms of `glDrawBuffers`; it's just a more restrictive form (sets index 0 to the give buffer and all others to `GL_NONE`). But neither is in GL ES 2.0.